# Firebase Firestore with Android Frontend. Design question: Security relavant code on frontend?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

assume we have a banking app with a firebase backend. We can see our current balance and we can add a transaction.

Now from coding perspective:

If we add a transaction we need to adjust the account balance. As this is security relevant (we do not want someone to manipulate the frontend and adjust the account balance) we only add the transaction and let the backend (firebase cloud function) execute it.

But now the account balance (the ui) will be unresponsive until the backend added the transaction and synched it to the frontend leading to a bad user experience.

Expected behaviour: An added transaction directly reflects to the account balance.

How to workaround this issue?

I have multiple ideas in my mind:

1. Let the frontend execute the transaction (Feels pretty bad)
2. Execute it on frontend AND backend where the frontend only writes to cache and the backend confirms or overwrite the caches result (Feels good, but how to only write to cache and not to sync?)
3. Manipulate the visible data on presentation layer until backend overwrites/confirms (Same as 2 but with same hacky way of doing this on presentation layer)

Note: I do not think this is an opinion based question. I think there are standard ways of doing such things thus I think this question is legit.

Any help appreciated

**EDIT:** It is not actually a banking app. This is an easy example to demonstrate the problem. The target application needs way less security then a banking app, still the issue stays

Comment: I am sorry but in my opinion everything regarding security is irrelevant after the decision using Firebase for a banking app.

Comment: Its not a banking app. I just needed an example that is easy and clear to understand.

Comment: Hey @Avinta, Is this issue resolved now?

Comment: No, the answer given is just the implementation of how it is working right now. My problem is the time difference between backend and frontend (I immediatly see the transaction because it is added to firebase by the frontend, but i do not see immediatly (need to wait couple of seconds) the outcome. So the user might get the idea that the prgram is broken and adds the transaction anew (sticking to the banking example)

Comment: Can you share the code and the error that you are getting?

Comment: There is no "code" or "error" to share. Everything works. It is a design question. The backend is updating data (due to security reasons) this takes time in which the user might think his request got lost. The question is how do other apps handle such situtations where the user expects to see an immediate result of his input but the backend needs time to process and the possibilities that come to my mind are listed in the question

Answer (score 1):

the thing with working directly with firebase as "back end" is that sometimes it's hard to [separate responsibilities between front and back](https://dev.to/ben/what-are-some-fundamentals-of-security-every-developer-should-understand-3ki3), leading to security issues.

The most important element is that you must NEVER trust just your user input, and have clear layer isolation, one way to achieve this could be to handle your transactions using [cloud functions](https://firebase.google.com/products/functions) so you only read data from your client code (also add some security so you are 100% no remote client is changing data), and run transactions through functions.

Comment: This is exactly what is happening right now. I have a cloud function handeling the user input on the backend. The only problem is, that the changes do not directly reflect in the UI for the user to be seen because the cloud function needs time to boot up and to apply the changes. But I want the user to see the change immediatly (Because this is what he expects. So my idea is to do the changes on frontend as well (of user data) and overwrite once backend is done

Comment: It really depends on the actual security that you are in need, another option is to have two sets of data, one for your frontend data, and another for the actual business info, then when something at the front end changes, you can use a trigger to validate the fe trx, then record it on the actual "backend" if it passes all your business rules, at the end the important part is that the fe won't be doing permanent changes to data directly